# Ошибка The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain, используя GraphQl

Tags: c#, ssl, graphql

Использую Graphql клиент.
Делаю запрос по адресу "Х"

```
var response = await _client.SendQueryAsync<GetMacroregionsResponse>(query);
```

и мне выдает ошибку с текстом:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

Делаю запрос через Postman ответ 200, все хорошо.
Почитал что это как-то связано с SSL. Почитал как его можно отключить, но проблема в том что там все используют обычный HttpClient, а я IGraphQLClient.
В Program.cs добавляю его так

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGraphQLClient>(s => new GraphQLHttpClient(configuration["GraphQL_uri"], new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()));
```

Почему через Postman запрос успешный, а через .Net такая ошибка и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Нет доверия сертификату сервера. Возможно, его стоит добавить в хранилище сертификатов. К GraphQL проблема не имеет отношения. Откройте любую страницу сайта от этого сервера в браузере и увидите проблему.

Comment: @aepot в браузере graphql схема там норм открывается. Через постман запросы туда тоже нормально идет

Comment: Постман может игнорировать невалидный сертификат. Это не показатель.

Comment: Такое может быть, если в Postman и браузере корневой сертификат сервера есть, а в .Net нет. Раздобудьте корневой сертификат для адреса `X` и добавьте его в хранилище доверенных сертификатов Windows.